# Meta теги с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать заполнение мета тегов с помощью php? То есть хочу заполнять их через html форму, заносить в базу, а при загрузке страницы чтобы они появлялись автоматически из базы.

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так а в чем проблема то я не понял? Ну создайте таблицу в которой, например будут хранится:
1)url
2)собственно самы мета теги

Ну и просто дергайте по значению `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
Но что-то я подозреваю что вам написаного выше будет мало...

Comment: Человек просто видимо еще не привык мыслить алгоритмами и структурами, для него название новости, имя пользователя и meta-keywords чем-то отличаются)

Comment: Всему свое время, по мне так все очень просто - практически все или `string` или `true` `false` ^^

Comment: на самом деле, строк тоже нет =) 

`'lol'=`<small>true true false true true false false false true true false true true true true false true true false true true false false </small>

Comment: не ну я же не на машинном коде всетаки пишу и если на то пошло...<br>
`11011000110111101101111`...<br><br> 
`true` и `false` тоже нету...

Comment: и понеслась ХД